# How to solve QPixmap::fromImage memory leak?

Tags: qt, memory-leaks, opencv, qimage, qpixmap

I have a problem with Qt.

Here is a part of code that troubles me:

```
    void FullScreenImage::QImageIplImageCvt(IplImage *input)
{
    help=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(input), input->depth, input->nChannels);
    cvCvtColor(input, help, CV_BGR2RGB);
    QImage tmp((uchar *)help->imageData, help->width, help->height, help->widthStep, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    this->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(tmp).scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
    cvReleaseImage(&help);
}


void FullScreenImage::hideOnScreen() {
    this->hide();
    this->clear();
}

void FullScreenImage::showOnScreen(IplImage *slika, int delay) {
    QImageIplImageCvt(slika);
    this->showFullScreen();
    if(delay>0)
 QTimer::singleShot(delay*1000, this, SLOT(hideOnScreen()));
}
```

So, the method `showOnScreen` uses private method `QImageIplImageCvt` to create `QImage` from `IplImage` (which is used by the OpenCV), which is then used to create `QPixmap` in order to show the image in full screen. `FullScreenImage` class inherits `QLabel`.

After some delay, the fullscreen picture should be hidden, so I use `QTimer` to trigger an event after some delay. The event handler is the `hideOnScreen` method which hides the label and should clear the memory.

The problem is the following:

Whenever I call `QPixmap::fromImage`, it allocates the memory for the pixmap data and copies the data from `QImage` memory buffer to the `QPixmap` memory buffer. After the label is hidden, the `QPixmap` data still remains allocated, and even worse, after the new `QPixmap::fromImage` call the new chunk of memory is allocated for the new picture, and the old data is not freed from memory. This causes a memory leak (cca 10 MB per method call with my testing pictures). How can I solve that leak?

I've even tried to create a private `QPixmap` variable, store pixmap created by the `QPixmap::fromImage` to it, and then tried to call its destructor in `hideOnScreen` method, but it didn't help.

Is there a non-static way to create `QPixmap` from `QImage`? Or even better, is there a way to create `QPixmap` directly from `IplImage*` ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create `QPixmap` directly from `IplImage*` (and also not from `cv::Mat`). However, your solution there is to refrain from writing everything into one line and work with a pointer that you free yourself.

e.g.:

```
if (this->mypixmap)
    delete this->mypixmap;
this->mypixmap = new QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(tmp).scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
this->setPixmap(this->mypixmap);
```

Don't forget to set `mypixmap(NULL)` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `QPixmap::loadFromData` to create a `QPixmap` directly. So something like the following might work:

```
QPixmap p;
p.loadFromData((uchar *)help->imageData, help->width * help->height);
```

Without knowing anything about OpenCV or `IplImage`, I can't guarantee that the above snippet is correct, but hopefully it starts you down the right path.

Comment: Does not work, as loadFromData is not designed for raw image data.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, however my code was different so its not worth me putting here.  Taking your code and merging with my method would give you:

```
void FullScreenImage::QImageIplImageCvt(IplImage *input)
{
    help=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(input), input->depth, input->nChannels);
    cvCvtColor(input, help, CV_BGR2RGB);
    QImage* tmp = new QImage((uchar *)help->imageData, help->width, help->height, help->widthStep, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    this->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*tmp).scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
    delete tmp;
    cvReleaseImage(&help);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the overloaded method solved the issue for me:

```
QPixmap::fromImage(const QImage && image,..)
```

You can call it with:

```
QPixmap::fromImage(std::move(tmp))
```